# Is there a synchronous equivalent for the Client method "exec" in ssh2 for node js?

Tags: node.js, client

I have connected to a remote machine using ssh2 in node js.
Now I want to run commands on the remote machine synchronously.

```
var Client = require('ssh2').Client;


var conn = new Client();
conn.on('ready', function() {
  console.log('Client :: ready');
  conn.exec('uptime', function(err, stream) {
    if (err) throw err;
    stream.on('close', function(code, signal) {
      console.log('Stream :: close :: code: ' + code + ', signal: ' + signal);
      conn.end();
    }).on('data', function(data) {
      console.log('STDOUT: ' + data);
    }).stderr.on('data', function(data) {
      console.log('STDERR: ' + data);
    });
  });
}).connect({
  host: '192.168.100.100',
  port: 22,
  username: 'frylock',
  privateKey: require('fs').readFileSync('/here/is/my/key')
});
```

This way i can execute it in an async way. If there any function equivalent to "exec" which is sync.

Answer (score 0):

Use conn.shell instead of conn.exec. With shell method you can start an interactive shell session.

Here an example :

https://github.com/mscdex/ssh2#start-an-interactive-shell-session